# Django pytest AssertionError: should return body unicode

Tags: python, django, pytest-django

I was learning **django-pytest** and Im trying to test the unicode, but was getting error

**My models**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    value = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body
```

**test**

```
class TestPost:
    def test_model(self):
        obj = mixer.blend('birdie.Post')
        assert obj.pk == 1, 'should create a post instance '

    def test_uniccode(self):
        obj = mixer.blend('birdie.Post',body='hello')
        result = obj.__unicode__
        assert result == 'hello', 'should return body unicode
```

Im having difficulty with testing unicode, I was just doing it to have 100% coverage

**error**
[image]

Any help is much appreciated in passing the test. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
object = obj
result = object.__unicode__()
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure, I don't understand why you unaccepted (it was accepted 1 month ago) my answer. It helped you. Its clearly. Maybe, you accepted answer of your friend. Well, good luck with that attitude.

You have to call

```
obj.__unicode__()
```

it should work fine.

It's a method, so call it like a method. Don't forget about brackets.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

obj = Group(name='test')
obj.save()

obj.__unicode__
<bound method Group.__unicode__ of <Group: test>>

obj.__unicode__()
u'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = unicode(obj)
result == u'hello'
```